# Algorithm to find largest prime number smaller than x

Tags: algorithm, primes

How do I calculate the largest prime number smaller than value x?

In actual fact, it doesn't have to be exact, just approximate and close to x.

x is a 32 bit integer.

The idea is that x is a configuration parameter.  I'm using the largest prime number less than x (call it y) as the parameter to a class constructor.  The value y must be a prime number.

Comment: I think you would maybe need to know some contextual primes to best solve this problem. Is that possible? X is not prime?

Comment: To what scale?  32-bit integers?  Or to cryto standards such as 1024-bit numbers?

Comment: x is going to be in the int32 range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some good info [here](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml#pi_def) on the function pi(x). Apparently,

```
pi(x) = the number of primes less than x
```

and you can approximate pi(x) with

```
x/(log x - 1)
```

while

```
the n-th prime of that list of primes is equal to approximately n(log n)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm after.  Close enough when you calculate the nth prime

Comment: Gauss's Li (the [offset logarithmic integral function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function)) is a much better estimator than *x* / (log *x* − 1) —— as Chris Caldwell explains at the linked page!

Comment: Wow, great answer and super interesting too! @GarethRees I don't understand what he means by:

> And we can see in the same way that the function Li(x)-(1/2)Li(x1/2) is 'on the average' a better approximation than Li(x) to pi(x); but no importance can be attached to the latter terms in Riemann's formula even by repeated averaging.

Answer (score 1):

How fast you need the program runs? And how frequently you calculate this problem?

If you need a fast achievement and don't care about the memory. You can generate an increasing prime table by sieve method then hold it during the program lifetime, and then when you what to find 'the largest prime number smaller than value x', just look up the table and in O(log N) time you can find an exact answer.

Comment: For smaller ranges of primes, this is almost certainly the fastest way to do this. All the two-byte primes (6542 of them) will fit in a 16kB L1 cache if stored as 16-bit values, and they'll fit in a 32kB L1 cache if stored as 32-bit values. All recent CPUs have at least a 32kB L1 data cache. The 1077871 primes that can be represented with 3 bytes each won't quite fit in a 4MB L2 cache if stored as 32-bit values, but will if you pack 5 of them into 16 bytes, which still lets you do an efficient binary search.