# Find a largest prime number less than n

Tags: algorithm, primes

How can I find a largest prime number which is less than n, where  n ≤ 10¹⁸ ?
Please help me find an Efficient Algorithm.

```
for(j=n;j>=2;j--) {
  if(j%2 == 1) {
    double m = double(j);
    double a = (m-1)/6.0;
    double b = (m-5)/6.0;
    if( a-(int)a == 0 || b-(int)b == 0 ) {
      printf("%llu\n",j);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I used this approach but this is not efficient to solve for n>10^10;

How to optimize this..

**Edit:** 
Solution: Use Primality test on each j.

[Miller Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), [Fermat's  Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test).

Comment: We insist that people ask programming questions here. Do some research, come up with an algorithm, and then if some aspect has you stumped come back here.

Comment: I did so many research on this ... used algos of complexity O(nlog(n)) but now want a more efficient..

Comment: You probably found this already, but still, it gives some references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741947/algorithm-to-find-largest-prime-number-smaller-than-x

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test . use some test from that page consecutively on numbers from n down, until the first success.  round down to an odd number, and step by step of (-2).

Comment: The use of floating-point is a good indicator that you've got the wrong idea here. Use `uint64_t` (or the equivalent).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=biggest+prime+below+10%5E18 :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this question should be so quickly dismissed, as *efficiency* is not so easy to determine for numbers in this range. First of all, given the average prime gap is `ln(p)`, it makes sense to work **down** from the given `(n)`. i.e., `ln(10^18) ~ 41.44)`, so you would expect around `41` iterations *on average* working down from `(n)`. e.g., testing: `(n), (n - 2), (n - 4), ...`

Given this *average* gap, the next step is to decide whether you wish to use a naive test - check for divisibility by primes `<= floor(sqrt(n))`. With `n <= (10^18)`, you would need to test against primes `<= (10^9)`. There are [~ 50 million](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Table_of_.CF.80.28x.29.2C_x_.2F_ln_x.2C_and_li.28x.29) primes in this range. If you are willing to precompute and tabulate these values (all of which fit in 32 bits), you have a reasonable test for 64-bit values `n <= 10^18`. In this case, is a 200MB prime table an acceptable approach? 20 years ago, it might not have been. Today, it's not an issue.

Combining a prime table with sieving and/or [Pocklington's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test) might improve efficiency. Alternatively, if memory is more constrained, a deterministic variant of the [Miller-Rabin test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) with bases: `2, 325, 9375, 28178, 450775, 9780504, 1795265022` [(SPRP set)](http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/). Most composites fail immediately with an SPRP-2 test.

The point is - you have a decision to make between algorithmic complexity, both theoretical and in terms of implementation difficulty, and a balance with space/time trade-offs.